# Resource no refresh when i use slow connection o 3G angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ionic-framework

I 'm creating a mobile application based on angularjs . To load a list , I'm making a call to an API Rest. I am using a resource for doing this. When I 'm connected to the wifi it works perfectly , but when I use · g, the recuerso not call the API and always returns the previous value.

How I can refresh the application each time you call?

**SERVICES.JS**

```
.factory('Exercises', function($resource) {

// localhost: Local
// 79.148.230.240: server
return $resource('http://79.148.230.240:3000/wodapp/users/:idUser/exercises/:idExercise', {
    idUser: '55357c898aa778b657adafb4',
    idExercise: '@_id'
}, {
    update: {
        method: 'PUT'
    }
});
```

});

**CONTROLLERS**

```
.controller('ExerciseController', function($q, $scope, $state, Exercises) {

         // reload exercises every time  when we enter in the controller
         Exercises.query(function(data) {
             $scope.exercises = data;
         });

         // refresh the list of exercises
         $scope.doRefresh = function() {

             // reload exercises
             Exercises.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
                 $scope.exercises = data;
             }, function(error) {
                 console.log('error');
             });

             // control refresh element 
             $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
             $scope.$apply();
         }

         // create a new execersie template
         $scope.newExercise = function() {
             $state.go('newExercise');
         };

         // delete a exercise
         $scope.deleteExercise = function(i) {

             // we access to the element using index param
             var exerciseDelete = $scope.exercises[i];

             // delete exercise calling Rest API and later remove to the scope
             exerciseDelete.$delete(function() {
                 $scope.exercises.splice(i, 1);
             });
         };
     })
```

**APP.js**

```
angular.module('wodapp', ['ionic', 'ngResource', 'wodapp.controllers','wodapp.services'])

// Run
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // ionic is loaded
  });
})

// Config
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('slide', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'templates/slides.html',
      controller: 'SlideController'
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'DashboardController'
    })
    .state('exercise', {
      url: '/exercise',
      templateUrl: 'templates/exercises.html',
      controller: 'ExerciseController'
    })
    .state('newExercise',{
      url: '/newExercise',
      templateUrl: 'templates/newExercise.html',
      controller: 'NewExerciseController'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Comment: When you test on a device (especially on Android now) do you have the domain whitelisted using Cordova? API calls would be blocked otherwise.

Comment: I am using ionic to develop this app. And my configuration i think it is fine...  <access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />

Comment: Whitelisting changed in recent Cordova and Android. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html I think you at least need to put a `*` to match all, and install the whitelist plugin for Android (not sure what platform you are using.

Comment: if it is , the + are set but have not been shown

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$ionicView` and then:

```
$ioniView.enter(function(){
 Exercises.query(function(data) {
   $scope.exercises = data;
  });
})
```

Comment: it does not work. I think the problems is the resource because it isn note refreshing!